# How do I quote a word that ends with a possessive apostrophe?

Tags: punctuation, apostrophe, quotation-marks

What is the correct way to enclose within double quotes a word that ends with a possessive apostrophe?

For example:

> The **"professionals'"** confidence was badly shaken by the market crash.

I used quotes around `professionals'` to emphasize that they are merely self-proclaimed "professionals" as opposed to real professionals. Did I use double quotes correctly? Should it be `"professionals'"`, `"professionals"'`, or `"professional"s'`?

Comment: There is no one right way to present this; such things are a matter of style. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, adopt a [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) appropriate to your audience and tastes and be consistent in its application.

Answer (score 6):

The original sentence is correct, but I agree that it can look ugly.

There is at least three possible solutions to this:

1. Don't use the posessive. You could instead say:

> The confidence of the "professionals" was badly shaken by the market crash.

2. Use the more specialized punctuation marks **'**, **“**, and **”** to help distinguish them to readers.
3. As you are using the quotation marks to add sarcasm rather than actually quote somebody, you could use an entirely different approach, for example:

> The confidence of the so-called-professionals was badly shaken by the market crash.

Comment: So, in Word, there is a very tiny space between a possessive apostrophe and the double quotation marks (all curly or *smart* type), which is intended to distinguish them. Using two different kinds (*smart* and *straight*) may not be wise for something formal, where consistency is required. But I like your other suggestion about rephrasing.

Answer (score 3):

Short of rephrasing the sentence (which is possible), most style guides address this by suggesting putting a space between the apostrophe and quotation mark in order to make the presentation clearer to readers.

Before:

> The "professionals'" confidence was badly shaken by the market crash.

After:

> The "professionals' " confidence was badly shaken by the market crash.

With access to typesetting tools, you can also use what's called a *thin space*, which is not as wide as a regular full-sized space. This retains the separation between the apostrophe and quotation mark without it looking like there's to much of a gap. But I can't demonstrate that, because this site seems to treat the thin space character as just a regular space.

---

From [*The Chicago Manual of Style*, 6.11](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch06/psec011.html) [paywall]:

> When single quotation marks are nested within double quotation marks, and two of the marks appear next to each other, a space between the two marks, though not strictly required, aids legibility. For print publications, typesetters may place a thin space or a hair space between the two marks (as in the print edition of this manual). In electronic environments (including manuscripts submitted for publication), a nonbreaking space can be used (as in the online edition of this manual); such a space will prevent the second mark from becoming stranded at the beginning of a new line.